# Meteor.js Discover Meteor Book Error While Simulating Effect Of

Tags: meteor

I'm working through the Meteor book called Discover Meteor, and I am in chapter 7 section 6. I am trying to user Meteor.methods to create the post function for the web app. When I hit the submit button, the following error appears: 
[image]

i.e,

```
http://localhost:3000 Internal server error
```

The JS Console:

```
[Log] Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'post'  (meteor.js, line 733)
Error
line: 24
message: "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_.post(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message')')"
sourceURL: "http://localhost:3000/collections/posts.js?fc84533d5acd5a26ddd07233ffdf1c6d50eb03ae"
stack: "post@http://localhost:3000/collections/posts.js?fc84533d5acd5a26ddd07233ffdf1c6d50eb03ae:24:35↵http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?edca5d3826d0b2bd3507cac956e98d83559da4d8:4140:30↵withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:793:21↵apply@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?edca5d3826d0b2bd3507cac956e98d83559da4d8:4131:63↵call@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?edca5d3826d0b2bd3507cac956e98d83559da4d8:4021:22↵[native code]↵submit form@http://localhost:3000/client/views/posts/post_submit.js?5b0a8174d424b90c1cf9682a03b94dcfe2985f85:10:20↵http://localhost:3000/packages/templating.js?e2c0d3bbe4292a0b20c3083eaf4fcd0f5f91bb52:120:23↵http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2205:35↵withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2038:16↵http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2204:41↵http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:802:29↵dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:4657:14↵handle@http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:4325:33"
__proto__: Error
post@http://localhost:3000/collections/posts.js?fc84533d5acd5a26ddd07233ffdf1c6d50eb03ae:24:35
http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?edca5d3826d0b2bd3507cac956e98d83559da4d8:4140:30
withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:793:21
apply@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?edca5d3826d0b2bd3507cac956e98d83559da4d8:4131:63
call@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?edca5d3826d0b2bd3507cac956e98d83559da4d8:4021:22
[native code]
submit form@http://localhost:3000/client/views/posts/post_submit.js?5b0a8174d424b90c1cf9682a03b94dcfe2985f85:10:20
http://localhost:3000/packages/templating.js?e2c0d3bbe4292a0b20c3083eaf4fcd0f5f91bb52:120:23
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2205:35
withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2038:16
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2204:41
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:802:29
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:4657:14
handle@http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:4325:33
```

My router.js:

Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

```
Meteor.methods({
    post: function(postAttributes) {
        var user = Meteor.user(),
            postWithSameLink = Posts.findOne({url: postAttributes.url});

        // user is not logged in
        if(!user) {
            throw new Meteor.error(401, "You need to login to post new stories.")
        };

        // no title
        if(!postAttributes.title) {
            throw new Meteor.error(422, "Please fill in a headline.");
        };

        // no posts with same link
        if(postAttributes.url && postWithSameLink) {
            throw new Meteor.error(302, "This link has already been posted.", postWithSameLink._id);
        };

        // pick whitelisted keys
        var post = _.extend(_.post(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message'), [{
            userId: user._id,
            author: user.username,
            submitted: new Date().getTime()

        }]);

        var postId = Posts.insert(post);
        return postId;
    }
})
```

post_submit.js:

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post = {
            url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
            title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
            message: $(e.target).find('[name=message]').val()
        }

        Meteor.call('post', post, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                return alert(error.reason);
            }
            Router.go('postPage', post);
        })

    }

})
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

Instead of

```
var post = _.extend(_.post(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message'), [{
  userId: user._id,
  author: user.username,
  submitted: new Date().getTime()
}]);
```

you should have typed

```
var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message'), [{
  userId: user._id,
  author: user.username,
  submitted: new Date().getTime()
}]);
```

Notice the use of `_.pick` instead of `_.post` where `_.pick(object, *keys)` is an [underscorejs object utility](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) which *returns a copy of the object, filtered to only have values for the whitelisted keys (or array of valid keys).*

```
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'name', 'age');
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```

Comment: This got rid of the initial error, but I'm now getting another:

Comment: After a little bit more testing, I found that the error throwing works, and that it adds the post, it just doesn't redirect there. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: It looks like the new problem is somewhere within post_submit.js but it is another question. If my answer replies your question, then you should accept it, post a new question with the new information. Don't include imgur links, paste in the screenshot itself, better yet, copy and paste the error. Also, I'd make sure not to have any more typos. You can compare your code against the github repo of Microscope.